# how to find consecutive numbers in a sequence

Tags: c++

im trying to a write a program that accepts 10 random integers and checks whether there are three consecutive numbers in the sequence or not.The consecutive numbers can be in ascending or descending order. 
here are some examples to help you understand better:
order. Examples:

2  9  8  3  20  15  9  6  4  24
Yes,  2  3 and 4 are consecutive

16  21  3  8  20  6  3  9  12  19
Yes, 21  20 and 19 are consecutive

I can't figure out whats wrong with my code.
here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a[10];
int i,n;
int count=0;


cout << "Enter 10 numbers between 1 and 25" << endl;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{             cin >> a[i];

}


for (n=0; n<10; n++)
{
    for (i=1; i<10; i++)
    { 
        if (a[i]==a[n]+1)
        {cout<<endl<<a[i]<<endl;
        count++;}
    }

}

}
```

Comment: The inner loop should start from `n+1`, not from `1`.

Comment: i would simply return true always, chances are quite low that this will give the wrong result :P

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: No, that should not be the case. For example, 7 6 8 will not be detected by that logic, even though they are consecutive. This is assuming that there are three loops to check for consecutive numbers, as opposed to the 2 currently.

Comment: @Malak it seems like it would be better to sort the array first and then check for consecutive numbers.  You probably wouldnt need multiple nested loops, and the logic would be simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is currently O(N<sup>2</sup>), and to get it to work it'll be O(N<sup>3</sup>).

I'd rather use an algorithm that's O(N) instead.

Given that you only care about 25 values, you can start with a 32-bit word, and set the bit in that word corresponding to each number that was entered (e.g., `word |= 1 << input_number;`).

Then take a value of `7` (which is three consecutive bits set) and test it at the possible bit positions in that word to see if you have three consecutive bits set anywhere in the word. If so, the position at which they're set tells you what three consecutive numbers you've found. If not, then there weren't three consecutive numbers in the input.

```
for (int i=0; i<32-3; i++) {
    int mask = 7 << i;
    if (word & mask == mask)
        // three consecutive bits set -> input contained i, i+1 and i+2
}
```

Comment: Very nice way of dealing with this situation. Just to show a complete example working http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a8170caaf1616f9

Comment: this is an awesome solution, and I'm guessing probably over the asker's head.  Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. What your current code does is that it checks if there are any two consecutive integers. To check for three, you should introduce another nested loop. This would make the time complexity O(n^3).

Another possible way to check this is to first sort the array, and then check for consecutive elements. This would make the running time O(nlogn). You can use the inbuilt `sort` function for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm needs to be reworked. As it is, what you are doing is saying:

```
For each array element x
     See if another array element is x+1
         print out the array element that is x+1
```

Stick in more cout lines to see what is going on, like

```
    if (a[i]==a[n]+1)
    {cout<<endl<<a[n]<<","<<a[i]<<endl;
    count++;}
```

A possible, although slow, algorithm would be

```
For each array element x
     See if another array element is x+1
          See if another array element is x+2
             print out x, x+1, and x+2
```

Comment: This should be a comment.